Load a JSON via k8s Configmap into Angular
I have a small angular web application running in a k8s cluster which has some json config in the assets/text_content folder. It works with the following code
fetch('assets/text_content/albums.json').then(res => res.json()).then((result: AlbumItem[]) => { result.sort((a: AlbumItem, b: AlbumItem) => new Date(b.eventDate).getTime() - new Date(a.eventDate).getTime());
  }) 

This code in the ngOnInit method. Not the most pretty code, but it works. (First make it work)
Now I want it to make configurable by setting the JSON via a configmap so I did the following steps;
Changed NGINX
location /assets/text_content/ {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

Added ConfigMap
    apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: album-config
data:
  albums.json: |
    [
      {
        "eventDate": "2021-6-5",
        "eventName": "Toer",
        "albumUrl": "https://url.com"
      }
]

Updated the deployment
              volumeMounts:
            - name: config-volume
              mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/text_content/albums.json
              subPath: albums.json
      volumes:
        - name: config-volume
          configMap:
            name: album-config
            items:
              - key: albums.json
                path: albums.json

Deployed this with Helm and verified updated json exists under the path with
kubectl cp test-pod-86cb8b45bf-24w4h:/usr/share/nginx/html/assets/text_content/albums.json ./albums.json

Questions

Why doesn't this get picked up by Angular, it is static content in the end right? I just replace the file in assets/text_content/
Is it maybe something to do with SSR, which I implement in de dockerfile? I want to keep using this for findability of the website. Ill post the df below.
Is my assumption about file overwriting right?
So I checked if the file is available in the pod, what more can I do to debug this or is there a simple answer?
Angular fetch has no caching or something right? Each time the component goes to the location and fetches the json?

So it is verified that the configmap does its job, so I think it is an angular thing which I do not understand.
Dockerfile
### STAGE 1: Build ###
FROM node:18.10-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build:ssr

### STAGE 2: Nginx ###
FROM nginx:1.17.1-alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/test /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 8080

### STAGE 3: Server Side Rendering (SSR)
FROM node:18.10-alpine AS ssr-server
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist ./dist
COPY package.json ./
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve:ssr"]

NGINX complete
    server {
    listen       80; #80 is a MUST! letsencrypt only goes to port 80
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /assets/text_content/ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

   # Forward requests to the node container which
   # renders on the server side:
   location ~ ^/(public)$ {
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
   }
}


After a blog post about runtime config for angular I saw a simple sentence

If you have an Angular Universal application (using Server Side Rendering), in deployment.yamlyou will need to mount the /dist/browser/assets/app.config.json folder as this is the assets folder for browser-side code.

I started to exec in the pod and found my albums.json at this location and altered the mount path in the deployment.yaml and it worked.
So yes, just static content and yes you can just overwrite the file.
